# XAML controls binding with another controls which are in datatemplate !

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatemplate

i have the following datatemplate in xaml and here i have textbox in datatemplate and button in normal XAML, what i really want is that i want to keep button be disabled until person enters something in textbox ? but its not working i have tried the follwing code

Please look into it and help me as well ! or is there any other way to do this let me know !

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="dataTemplateParameter">            
        <StackPanel Width="170" Height="Auto" Margin="5">
            <TextBlock Width="160" TextAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Text="{Binding Path=ParameterName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtboxParameter"  Width="160" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=ParameterValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </StackPanel>            
    </DataTemplate>
```

```
<Button  Grid.Row="6" Name="SearchSourceParamBtn" Content="Search" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="12,5,92,0" Height="20" Visibility="{Binding SearchSourceBtnVisibility}" Command="{Binding SearchCommand}">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text,x:ElementName=txtboxParameter}" Value="">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Thanks
nallskarthi

Comment: Yes you ppl are correct but wats the problem is parametervalue is not in tat viewmodel its from model directly connected !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by 
1) binding button to RelayCommand. Then,
2) Validate the "ParameterValue" in command's CanExecute delegate.

**Edit:**
The better way is to have the ParameterValue in ViewModel, but for some reason you won't do that. Then, create a static ChangeNotifyable property in VM, using this property do the validation in CanExecute delegate.

[image]

Comment: Yes you are correct but wats the problems is parameter value is not in tat viewmodel its from model directly connected !

Comment: ho. But, never bind a Model directly to View. that I would suggest.

Comment: Actually that is not model i am keeping separately like library

Answer (score 0):

Pls Validate the "ParameterValue" in the CanExecute delegate of Command object.